# Dagre Angular2 SystemJS module loading

Tags: angular, systemjs, dagre

Using Angular 2.4.0, tsc 2.3.1, I'm attempting to use Dagre with JointJS/graphlib for drawing graphs in Angular2 using SystemJS as a loader.

http://www.daviddurman.com/automatic-graph-layout-with-jointjs-and-dagre.html

I can't figure out how to get the 'dagre' object in the browser as required by JointJS
`var dagre = require('dagre');`

My Angular2 component includes
`import * as dagre from 'dagre';`

My SystemJS config:

```
(function () {
  System.config({
    map: {
        'dagre': '/static/libs/dagre/dagre.js'
    }
});
})();
```

Not being able to load dagre leads to an undefined error in JointJS when it attempts to call the dagre.layout:
`Cannot read property 'layout' of undefined`

```
// Executes the layout.
dagre.layout(glGraph, { debugTiming: !!opt.debugTiming });
```

Maybe this is a problem with the library not exporting itself or do I have to specify a format in my SystemJS config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm not sure exactly what fixed this, but I did three things:

1) `npm install -D @types/dagre`

2) `import * as dagre from dagre;` in my component.ts

3) added format: global to the SystemJS config

```
(function () {
  System.config({
    map: {
        'lodash': '/static/libs/lodash/index.js',
        'dagre': '/static/libs/dagre/dagre.js',
        'graphlib': '/static/libs/graphlib/grpahlib.umd.js',
    },
    meta: {
      'dagre': {
         format: 'global',
         deps: ['lodash'],
      },
      'graphlib': {
         format: 'global',
         deps: ['lodash'],
      }
    }
});
})();
```